# vncviewer, virt-viewer cannot open display

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, vnc, ubuntu-server

I am on ubuntu server and i have been looking up how to connect to local vm's through vnc to continue setup.
i install the vm's using

```
sudo virt-install --virt-type kvm --name debian-7 --ram 1024 
--location=http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-amd64/ 
--disk path=/tmp/debian-7-amd64-vm.img,size=5 --network network=default 
--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole --os-type=linux --os-variant=debianwheezy --
extra-args="priority=critical interface=auto debian-installer/language=en 
debian-installer/country=US debian-installer/locale=en_US keymap=us  
preseed/url=http://public.thornelabs.net/debian-7-wheezy-preseed.seed"
```

i have no idea what my problem is. i get the same basic error when i try to vnc into the server on display 0 (i know its on display 0 for a fact)

```
Cannot open display
```

any ideas? one person told me i should see if the vm disk is mounted. 
`mount` returns

```
/dev/mapper/shane--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,relatime,hugetlb)
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

`xhost si:localuser:root`

For startup: search for and launch **Startup Applications** utility, click the “Add” and:

**name:** whatever (ex: run graphical app as root)

**command:** `xhost si:localuser:root`

This works for sudo and pkexec.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty hack to do this

```
sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority virt-install ...
```

Basicly your X environment isn't being passed on from your user to root